# ConvertFrom-JSON to object

Tags: json, powershell, azure

It looks like the way I am expecting this to work doesn't. I want multiple objects returned, but it seems to be returning just one. It is beyond me how I do it.

A very simple JSON file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "value": "sa01"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "value": "nvn01"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to dynamically add the parameters and their values into a nice pscustomobject (that would look like the following with the above data):

```
ParameterName      | Value
===========================
storageAccountName | sa01
virtualNetworkName | nvn01
```

What I don't understand is why the following returns one object:

```
$TemplateParametersFile = "C:\Temp\deploy-Project-Platform.parameters.json"
$content = Get-Content $TemplateParametersFile -Raw

$JsonParameters = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $content
$JsonParameters.parameters | Measure-Object
```

Whilst writing this, I eventually found a solution that get's what I want, which I'll post in the answer section. Feel free to school me and improve...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do things a little differently, skipping the hashtable, and using the hidden `PSObject` property. So, picking up after you have the JSON data stored in `$content`, I would do something like this:

```
#Convert JSON file to an object
$JsonParameters = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $content

#Create new PSObject with no properties
$oData = New-Object PSObject

#Loop through properties of the $JsonParameters.parameters object, and add them to the new blank object
$JsonParameters.parameters.psobject.Properties.Name | 
    ForEach{ 
        Add-Member -InputObject $oData -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue $JsonParameters.parameters.$_.Value 
    }

$oData
```

By the way, it had issues converting the JSON you posted, I had to add quotes around the two values, such as `"value": "sa01"`.

Comment: Beautiful! So elegant when you know how! Why is it "hidden"? Sorry about the missing quotes. I changed the original value of null on the fly. Still getting used to JSON syntax. Updated in original question.

Comment: Well, PowerShell hides a lot of things by default. If they showed you everything you have access to all the time it would be kind of overwhelming. I believe that it is hidden because it references the base object that your custom object is derived from, but I may be wrong, I have nothing to back that but my own theory. You should pipe the `PSObject` to `| Get-Member -Force` and browse around it a bit, there's a lot you can learn about the objects you work with that way.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same JSON file as shown above:

```
<#
# Read in JSON from file on disk
$TemplateParametersFile = "C:\Temp\deploy-Project-Platform.parameters.json"
$content = Get-Content $TemplateParametersFile -Raw   
#>

#Retrieve JSON file from Azure storage account.
$TemplateParametersFile = "https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{SomeContainer}/deploy-Project-Platform.parameters.json"
$oWc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webpage = $oWc.DownloadData($TemplateParametersFile) 
$content = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($webpage)

#Convert JSON file to an object (IMHO- Sort of!)
$JsonParameters = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $content

#Build hashtable - easier to add new items - the whole purpose of this script
$oDataHash = @{}
$JsonParameters.parameters | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object{
    $oDataHash += @{
        $_.name = $JsonParameters.parameters."$($_.name)" | Select -ExpandProperty Value
    }
}

#Example: adding a single item to the hashtable
$oDataHash.Add("VirtualMachineName","aDemoAdd")

#Convert hashtable to pscustomobject
$oData = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject

$oData | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name AddNote -Value {
    Add-Member -InputObject $this -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $args[0] -Value $args[1]
} 

$oDataHash.Keys | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object{

    $oData.AddNote($_,$oDataHash.$_)
}

$oData
```

And the result:

```
storageAccountName VirtualMachineName virtualNetworkName
------------------ ------------------ ------------------
sa01               aDemoAdd           nvn01
```

Agreed, the question asked for a Parameter / Value pair, and this results in the parameter's name being assigned as the noteproperty, but I think it will be easier to use it this way. Of course, $oDataHash returns it as a Key/value pair.

This script also pulls the JSON file directly from an Azure storage account. No need to save to disk. If you want to save to disk, change $oWc.DownloadData() to $oWc.[DownloadFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) . The commented bit at the top, reads from disk.

I am sure there are much more succinct ways to achieve the same result, and I'd love to here them. For me, at the moment this works.